# TypeError: this._config.serializer.isThirdPartyModule is not a function

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, eas

I have updated my `expo` version from `48` to `49`.
I have built development build which is working fine but my preview build is failing with `TypeError: this._config.serializer.isThirdPartyModule is not a function`.

```
TypeError: this._config.serializer.isThirdPartyModule is not a function
    at Server._shouldAddModuleToIgnoreList (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-plugin-metro/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:1095:31)
    at Object.shouldAddToIgnoreList (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-plugin-metro/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:142:14)
    at getSourceMapInfo (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-plugin-metro/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Serializers/helpers/getSourceMapInfo.js:18:24)
    at processNextModule (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-plugin-metro/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Serializers/sourceMapGenerator.js:30:18)
    at workLoop (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-plugin-metro/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Serializers/sourceMapGenerator.js:40:22)
    at getSourceMapInfosImpl (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-plugin-metro/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Serializers/sourceMapGenerator.js:60:3)
    at sourceMapGenerator (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-plugin-metro/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Serializers/sourceMapGenerator.js:64:3)
    at sourceMapString (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-plugin-metro/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Serializers/sourceMapString.js:16:10)
    at Server.build (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-plugin-metro/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:165:19)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
> Task :app:createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets FAILED
w: Detected multiple Kotlin daemon sessions at build/kotlin/sessions
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.
You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.
See https://docs.gradle.org/8.0.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
1263 actionable tasks: 1263 executed
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:

Execution failed for task ':app:createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets'.
```

I have updated my `metro.config.js` file but all in vain

```js
// metro.config.js file
const { getDefaultConfig } = require('expo/metro-config');

const config = getDefaultConfig(__dirname);

config.transformer.getTransformOptions = async () => ({
  transform: {
    experimentalImportSupport: false,
    inlineRequires: true,
  },
});

module.exports = config;
```

Please help me out on this problem